# Дана строка с разделителем точкой, ее нужно поместить в вектор по разделителю. Почему в моем случае push_back не срабатывает? (С++)

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

string split_t(string s){
    vector <string> v;
    string delimiter=".";
    int first;
    int last=0;
    while((first = s.find_first_not_of(delimiter, last)) != s.size()){
        last=s.find(delimiter, first);
        v.push_back(s.substr(first, last-first));
    }

        
    return 0; 
}
int main(){
    split_t("aa.bb.cc.dd.ee");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае код вообще не компилируется...

Попробуйте [этот](https://ideone.com/t8KvbI):

```
vector<string> split_t(const string& s)
{
    vector <string> v;
    string delimiter=".";
    int first;
    int last=0;
    while((first = s.find_first_not_of(delimiter, last)) != s.npos)
    {
        last=s.find(delimiter, first);
        v.push_back(s.substr(first, last-first));
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это сработало!